# Subclass UIViewController to create a list programmatically without using a nib

Tags: iphone, ios

All I currently need is to create a tableview programmatically by subclassing UIViewController and applying the necessary methods from  without using any nib file. It will probably need a UINavigationViewControlloer. I basically understand all these concepts and even almost know how to piece everything together but something is missing. It will have 4 files. AppDelegate h/m and SomeNameViewcontroller h/m. I think the SomeNameViewController should have a property UITableView*

I've tried several ways and looked online but i keep getting a black screen with a navigationbar. It's incredibly frustrating and when i can get the tableView to show, I can't get the tableView to reload data :/

Answer (score 3):

From your narrative, it seems that you do not fully grasp the concepts involved. For example, there is no such thing as a `UINavigationViewController`. Here is what you need to know:

- A `UINavigationController` is a controller of view controllers.

You can create it in your app delegate with

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
   yourRootViewController];
```

and access it from the view controller with `self.navigationController`.

- For your purposes, you create a subclass of a `UITableViewController`. The template in Xcode should already have stubs of all the `datasource` and `delegate` methods you need.
- In your app delegate, make sure you have assigned the right navigation controller as the root.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
self.window.rootViewController = nav; // the nav controller you created
[nav release];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Also remember that if the navigation controller is the root controller of the app and you're not using a xib at all, then you can delete the xib, clear the ref to it in the app-info.plist and you need to add it to this call in main.m:     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"YouAppDelegate");

Comment: @mundi. indeed. sorry for the confusion on my part. while i did say UINavigationViewController, i meant UINavigationController. but thats beside the point. Your answer did definitely help. I just have one more question. Instead of when creating a subclass of `UITableViewController` i would like to create a subclass of `UIViewController` and implement methods from the `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableviewSource>` and have that work as my yourRootViewController.

Comment: Creating a subclass of `UIViewController` and adding the delegate protocols and methods manually is also fine. Be sure to set the `view` of your view controller to the `tableView` or otherwise reference the table view consistently. Also, don't forget to set the table view's `datasource` and `delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need a `UITableVIewController`. And like Mundi mentioned, xcode takes care of this very well. Here is what you have to do:

1. Create a new project in XCode and choose the `Window-based Application` template.

   - This gives you the basic stuff, mainly a AppDelegate.

     ---
2. Add a new file that is a `UIViewController subclass`. When given the option change the subclassing to UITableViewController.

   - After that you will be given the option to use a nib file, uncheck that.
   - This will give you a UITableViewController with a UITableView already wired (`Delegate` and`DataSource`) to that controller.

     ---
3. Create your `NavigationController` in the `AppDelegate` and push your `TableViewContoller`.

   - `[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourTableViewController animated:NO];`

     ---
4. Setup your `NavigationContoller` as the `RootController` like Mundi described.

Sections 6 and 7 of the Stanford [Developing Apps for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598) explain `NavigationControllers` and other controllers (e.g. `TabBarController`) very well.